# Is SFMC down it keeps logging me out

Tags: marketing-cloud, error

Things were fine until about 5 minutes ago then it started logging me out everytime i signed back in..anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Please note, this is not the type of question for Stack Exchange.  As the answer says, please use Trust.MarketingCloud.com to check or ask SFMC support.

Comment: will delete my bad

Comment: Cant delete it cos someone has "invested time and effort into answering it" @Gortonington

Comment: no worries - Just keep it in mind for the future. Be aware this may be flagged and closed though.

Comment: Already flagged it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [trust.marketingcloud.com](https://trust.marketingcloud.com/):

> 2017-08-02 19:40 UTC - The Salesforce Marketing Cloud Technology Team is currently investigating a disruption with logins to all stacks in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
>
> This disruption began at 19:11 UTC 2017-08-02. Engineers are currently working to resolve the problem. During this time, a subset of customers may be experiencing a disruption with application logins, sends, synchronous api calls, imports, exports, and reporting.

Always try checking [trust.salesforce.com](https://trust.salesforce.com/en/) whenever you experience an outage.

Comment: [PostMortem live event](https://engage.vevent.com/rt/events_salesforce/log_thru.jsp?seid=194&standaloneparam=txnMJJDz-akcSzOvg93i2u6VXKnKwq14Mv7ZtIeszVlQrBfYtNu2gNGTJim_5wh-LqAHfHbAEMjj16dDlG4f7hSc8DVOfI9KpV7yO6B86rE).  Have to use IE for Flash.